# getting null when reading csv values

Tags: spring, opencsv

I need to import a csv file and get all its data but when I'm running this code, Im getting null as values but In the same time when Im printing number of rows, it's giving me the right number

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file){
    CsvToBean<Person> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                                        .withType(Person.class)
                                        .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                                        .build();
                                List<Person> records = csvToBean.parse();
                                
                                System.out.println(records.size());
                            if(records.size() ==0) {
                                model.addAttribute("message_file", "Aucune donnée trouvée dans le fichier importé");
                                model.addAttribute("code_file", "000");
                            }
                            for(int i = 0; i<records.size(); i++){
                               System.out.println(records.get(i).getid());
                               
                             }
.....
}


Person class :

@Entity
@Table(name = "Person", schema = "MXP")
public class Person implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "XPerson")

    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "PERSON_NAME")
    private String name;

    //..getters and setters
```

Do you have any Idea, how to extract data ?

Comment: can you share with us your model "Person"? Because we need to check the annotations there.
Also, you are using .withType(Bank.class), you need to map to a Bank or a Person?

Comment: I added the class "Person" in body, For the map its for Person (i just did a mistake when writing this question )

Comment: In your model class "Person", you should use OpenCsv annotations like @ CsvBindByPosition or @ CsvBindByName to do the mapping.
Take a look on this https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv